# How can I install an NPM package for a different user?

Tags: node.js, npm, chef-infra

I'm currently writing a chef script to provision a Windows 7 build machine for our environment. One of our dependencies is an NPM package which needs to be installed on two separate user accounts. However, NPM packages on Windows are installed locally to a user. Does anyone know a command I can execute to install an NPM package for the second user while logged in as the first user?

Comment: Have you tried using `runas` (requires a password to be set for the user)?

Comment: @Archimedix `runas` requires a password, this needs to be unattended

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Copy and paste the package. It is that simple!

**Long answer:** There is only one prerequisite: You must be able copy and paste the necessary files where they must be. In this case, either you have administrative privileges (in which case you carry out method 1) or you can log in as both user accounts (in which case you carry out method 2). I assume this is a standard Windows deployment scenario, where you make a template machine image with template profiles and then duplicate it to other machines.

***Method 1***

1. Install node.js (Run it installer, e.g. node-v0.12.7-x64.msi)
2. Run "Node.js command prompt" from the Start menu
3. Order the installation of the first package with the following command:

   ```
   npm install -g [package name]
   ```

   ...where [package name] is the name of your package. Verify that the installation is successful. (Important)
4. Repeat step 3 to install additional packages.
5. Enter the following commands:

   ```
   cd %appdata%
   explorer .
   ```

   Please verify that you are in a folder whose path is something similar to "C:\Users[Your username]\AppData\Roaming\" where "[Your username]" is the name of your user account. ("C:\" portion might be different.)
6. Locate two folders called `npm` and `npmcache`
7. Copy these two folders to the target users' profiles. The target folders must have the same path as the one I introduced in step 5, only instead of "[Your username]", it is their usernames.

You must either have administrative privileges to carry out step 7.

***Method 2***
Same as method 1, but before carrying out step 3, log in as the first user that should receive the package. Carry out steps 3 and 4 only. Once the installation is successful, log out and log in as the next user. Repeat steps 3 and 4.

You can mix and match too. e.g., carry out method 2, then have an admin copy the files for the second user as highlighted in the step 5 through 7 of method 1.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I've got a hacky solution. It's not pretty, but it's functional.

```
mkdir C:\\nodejs
npm config set prefix C:\\nodejs
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\\nodejs
npm install -g <package>
```

Make a node directory, tell node to install packages there, add it to the path so everyone can find it, then install the package. Like I said, hacky, but it's working ok.